# Create sprites automatically

Tags: .net, css, css-sprites

I get the folder with the following structure from my designer*:

> file.css
>
> images/

Is there any tool which can automatically create sprite for images folder and replace all images references from file.css to appropriate sprite sections?

*It is actually not a designer (the man who creates design in, for example, Photoshop) but the man who makes html+css from it. How is this profession correctly called in English? In russian  we have a separation into "дизайнер" (designer) and "верстальщик" (I would verbatim translate it as "markuper"). I am pretty sure there is the same separation in English.

**Update.**

I have found [Sprite and Image Optimization](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/61896) library which is probably what I was looking for.

Comment: I think you're looking for the word "developer" :-)

Comment: Actually, this should be the sitebuilder's job, not yours. I normally use [SpriteCow](http://www.spritecow.com/) to create my sprites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use .NET a nice framework is [**Sprite & Image Optimization**](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) and you can find a nice Video tutorial to start with

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URuuSlLZcX0

And even [Scott Hanselmen](http://www.hanselman.com) has a [nice tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek1ASPNETSpriteAndImageOptimization.aspx) as well regarding this framework.